# Jackson's ObjectMapper failed when parsing a date with 7 character milliseconds

Tags: json, jackson

I'm currently encountering the title above, here's what I'm working:

We have a .net application that sends a json formatter string message into a bus. The message is retrieved successfully in this format "2014-04-07T15:20:40.7439627Z", as you can see the length of millisecond segment is 7 characters (normally we have 3).

The problem is using ObjectMapper from jackson library, the parsing / conversion failed. The example above generated: Mon Apr 07 19:24:39 CEST 2014.

Also we are sure that it's not a timezone issue because when we use a millisecond value with only 3 characters, it worked.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the format from the source so I'm stuck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this problem by first transforming XmlGregorianCalendar to a Date object using a jaxb binding and by using a custom serializer for the objectMapper module from jackson library. I've explained my solution here:
http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.fr/2014/04/create-custom-json-string-deserializer.html